# Using Identity Framework 3.0 from .Net 4.6 assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

I am attempting to create and modify users and roles from a .Net 4.6 application using the new Identity Framework 3 (3.0.0-rc1) in ASP.Net 5.

From what I can find when searching for an answer it should be as simple as:
`var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(destination));`

However RoleManager constructor requires 6 parameters:
`public RoleManager(IRoleStore<TRole> store, IEnumerable<IRoleValidator<TRole>> roleValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, ILogger<RoleManager<TRole>> logger, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor);`

ASP.Net 5 uses IoC to provide UserManager and RoleManager and it seems to be closely tied to the setup of the server.

How can I modify Identity Framework 3 users and roles from a .Net 4.6 assembly?